# How can i load the stanli pack (of tikz) into lyx?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, stanli

I'm an engineering student and I'm trying to use the "TikZ Library for Structural Analysis" in **LyX** but can't load it in ([the pack](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/stanli/stanli.pdf)).
I have tried using: `\usepackage{structuralanalysis}`, and `\usetikzlibrary{structuralanalysis}` but LyX failed to load it in.

does anyone know how can I load it in so I'l will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called `stanli`, try

```
\usepackage{stanli}
```

in Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error msg, but it doesn't show me the actual picture

Comment: @YonatanMarom You haven't said anything about what you've done, it's completely impossible for me to guess why some diagram, of which I know nothing, doesn’t appear :) I think I'd suggest posting a new question where you include details about how you tried to make a diagram, and what happens.

Comment: I have tried copying an example diagram from the manual. the problem is that when I output the document it showed me nothing.

Comment: @YonatanMarom Please make a new question altogether, and include in it the generated LaTeX code, which you can find under View -> Code preview pane. Select *complete source* in the dropdown on the right side of that pane.

Comment: @YonatanMarom I should add, please do this with a new, empty document, containing only the diagram.